# Where/how can I find somebody to help me packaging an application for Ubuntu in my area?

Tags: ppa, packaging

I would like to learn how to package [an application](ftp://opendtect.org/pub/devel/) to a PPA which available in source code and GPL licensed. I would like to learn how to do it myself. Is there a way to find Ubunteros in my area to meet (San Francisco - San Jose)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ubuntu has Local Community (LoCo) Teams all over the world](http://loco.ubuntu.com/about-loco/). Copy/paste from the website for this:

> About Local Community (LoCo) Teams

With the incredible success of Ubuntu around the world, the LoCo project is here to help groups of Ubuntu fans and enthusiasts work together in regional teams to help advocate, promote, translate, develop and otherwise improve Ubuntu. Our worldwide network of LoCo teams is providing a strong backbone to our already vast and extensive Ubuntu community. Why not go and see the full list of teams!
Joining a LoCo Team

> Do you want to join a LoCo Team?

It's easy! Just find a team in your area and click the 'Join This Team!' link at the top of their page.
If you are not able to find a LoCo Team in your area and want to create one, take a look at the LoCo Team HowTo for more information on setting up a LoCo Team.

> Why Local Teams?

Ever since the birth of computers, enthusiasts and fans around the world have collected together in garages, universities and pubs to talk about their interest, learn from each other and help promote their interest. Combine this with the huge popularity of Ubuntu, and you have the Ubuntu LoCo project.

---

But the most interesting page for you would be the information on the [Ubuntu California](http://loco.ubuntu.com/teams/ubuntu-california) LoCo team. Pay them a visit and I bet there will be more than several people that can help you.

The next event for this LoCo team:

- When:  Wed, 05 Dec. 2012 18:00 - 19:00 PST
- Where:    The Roastery in San Francisco
- Event Contact:    Elizabeth Krumbach
- Organizing Team(s):   Ubuntu California
- Global Event: Ubuntu Hour

Maybe you will not get an answer but you are sure the get alot of pointers, tips and links to good information or an exchange of e-mail addresses.

Comment: Thanks! I had it already in mind. Obviously it is THE (only?) option to get started locally.